How to create ASEV3 resource using AzAPI terraform provider
I Was trying to create a ASEv3 resource using the AzAPI Terraform provider using
resource "azapi_resource" "ase" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments@2024-04-01"
  name      = "my-app-service-environment"
 location  = "eastus2"
 parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
 schema_validation_enabled = false
 body = jsonencode({
   properties = {
     internalLoadBalancingMode = "None"
    virtualNetwork = {
    id = "/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupid}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetname}/subnets/{subnetname}"
  }
  frontEndScaleFactor       = 15
  multiSize                 = "Standard_D1_V2"
  ipsslAddressCount         = 2
   }
 })
}

but unfortunately it is failing saying the below issue
           RESPONSE 400: 400 Bad Request
         │ ERROR CODE UNAVAILABLE
         │ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        │ {
        │   "Code": "BadRequest",
        │   "Message": "App Service Environment v1 is not supported for your 
        subscription. Please create using App Service Environment v3.",
       │   "Target": null,
      │   "Details": [
      │     {
      │       "Message": "App Service Environment v1 is not supported for your 
    subscription. Please create using App Service Environment v3."
     │     },
         │     {
       │       "Code": "BadRequest"
        │     },
       │     {
       │       "ErrorEntity": {
        │         "ExtendedCode": "55944",
        │         "MessageTemplate": "App Service Environment v{0} is not supported for 
   your subscription. Please create using App Service Environment v3.",
       │         "Parameters": [
       │           "1"
       │         ],
       │         "Code": "BadRequest",
       │         "Message": "App Service Environment v1 is not supported for your 
    subscription. Please create using App Service Environment v3."
       │       }
       │     }
       │   ],
      │   "Innererror": null
     │ }
       │ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I couldn't find a way to choose the APP service Environemnt Version to V3 in  AZAPI terraform provider
Note:
The reason why i'm trying the AzAPI provider is because the ASE resource creation with AzureRM provider is timing out in 2 hours when running from Terraform workspace and here I'm trying to find out any difference with AzAPI provider

You need to specify "kind": "ASEV3" in the request body at least. I don't use Terraform, but I'm guessing it would be something like this:
resource "azapi_resource" "ase" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments@2024-04-01"
  name      = "my-app-service-environment"
 location  = "eastus2"
 parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
 schema_validation_enabled = false
 body = jsonencode({
   kind = "ASEV3"
   properties = {
     internalLoadBalancingMode = "None"
    virtualNetwork = {
    id = "/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupid}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetname}/subnets/{subnetname}"
  }
  frontEndScaleFactor       = 15
  multiSize                 = "Standard_D1_V2"
  ipsslAddressCount         = 2
   }
 })
}


Let me try, I gave "kind": "ASEV3" below the type and name and it went unrecognized

It worked , Thank you @juunas
